# Spark default partitioning behaviour

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a bit confused about the number of `partitions` and its size in `spark`. Some tutorials refers number of `partitions = number of blocks in HDFS(64 mb or 128mb)` and other refers number of `partitions = number of cores` in cluster. So if my data is of 1 gig size and stored in `HDFS` of 128 mb `block size` and `cluster` has supoose 10 cores, so what will be the number of partitions in this case? Is it 8 or 10?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you import from hdfs it is number of blocks in hdfs .

Comment: refering https://techmagie.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/understanding-spark-partitioning/ which mentions for sc.textFile(), partition.size = sc.defaultParallelism or number of file blocks , whichever is greater. So for my scenario Is the answer is 10?